# Bypass for function having return type as Collection<T>

Tags: c#, function, collections

I have a function that is supposed to return a Collection < T > type; it's T because the Collection object will be different everytime which means the return type of the function needs to be generic. But Collection < T > return types gives an error as "T is not recognizable, are you missing a reference?" when I declare the function as public static Collection < T > func_name().

Any means of bypassing this?

Thanks...

Answer (score 4):

You should declare it as

```
public static Collection<T> func_name<T>() ...
```

You can drop the second T if the function is defined inside a class that already has a generic parameter T.

Answer (score 3):

You can't write:

```
public static Collection<T> func_name()
{
    // Implementation
}
```

How would the function know what type to return ?

You have to specify in the method declaration that it requires the type of `T` to be specified:

```
public static Collection<T> func_name<T>()
{
    // Implementation
}

...

Collection<string> obj = func_name<string>();
```

---

Note that is some cases, the compiler can **infer** which type is used (it's called **type inference**). It doesn't change the method declaration, but it can simply the usage of the method:

```
public static Collection<T> func_name<T>(T param)
{
}

private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string paramAsString = string.Empty;

    // Type inference here: the compiler know which is the type
    // represented by T as the parameter of the method that must 
    // be of type T is a string (so, for the compiler, T == string)
    // That's why in this example it's not required to write:
    // var obj = func_name<string>(paramAsString);
    // but following is enough:
    // var obj = func_name(paramAsString);
    Collection<string> obj = func_name(paramAsString);

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

---

I would suggest you to have a look to [generics in C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/512aeb7t%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Declare it as

```
public static Collection<T> func_name<T>()
```

This is called 'generic' in C# and is somewhat similar to C++ template classes/functions. You may find some basic information on C# generics and many useful links in [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/512aeb7t%28VS.80%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all your help!

I have decided to serialize the function to make it generic.